# How can I cast an array of [AnyObject] to an array of [Hashable] or [AnyHashable] in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of AnyObjects (`[AnyObject]`). I know most of these are `Hashable`.  How would I "cast" this AnyObject to a Hashable/AnyHashable?
AnyHashable only takes a Hashable object as a parameter.

Comment: use compactMap function

Comment: Well, don't use `AnyObject` in the first place. There should be very few places where you actually need to use `Any` or `AnyObject`. Usually only for a short time.

Answer (score 2):

To cast one object to another you use `as`. But the objects that can not be automatically converted (which is your case) you need to use either `as?` or `as!`. So the most simple way:

```
let hashableArray: [AnyHashable] = array as! [AnyHashable] // Will crash if even one object is not convertible to AnyHashable
let hashableArray: [AnyHashable]? = array as? [AnyHashable] // Will return nil if even one object is not convertible to AnyHashable
```

So one may crash while the other one will produce an optional array.

Since you wrote "I know most of these are `Hashable`" I would say that none of these are OK. You need to do the transform per-object and decide what to do with the rest. The most basic approach is:

```
func separateHashable(inputArray: [AnyObject]) -> (hashable: [AnyHashable], nonHashable: [AnyObject]) {
    var hashableArray: [AnyHashable] = [AnyHashable]()
    var nonHashableArray: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
    inputArray.forEach { item in
        if let hashable = item as? AnyHashable {
            hashableArray.append(item)
        } else {
            nonHashableArray.append(item)
        }
    }
    return (hashableArray, nonHashableArray)
}
```

So this method will convert your array and split it into two arrays. You could then simply do `let hashableArray: [AnyHashable] = separateHashable(inputArray: array).hashable`.

But if you want to only extract those items that are hashable you can use convenience method on array `compactMap`

```
let hashableArray: [AnyHashable] = array.compactMap { $0 as? AnyHashable }
```

But in general this all very dangerous. And also that is why you can't simply convert it to `Hashable`. The reason for it is that 2 items may both be hashable but are of different class. And then both of the items may produce same hash even though they do not represent the same item. Imagine having 2 classes:

```
struct Question: Hashable {
    let id: String
    var hashValue: Int { return id.hashValue }

}

struct Answer: Hashable {
    let id: String
    var hashValue: Int { return id.hashValue }
}
```

Now if I create an array like this:

```
let array: [AnyObject] = [
    Question(id: "1"),
    Answer(id: "1")
]
```

both of the items would produce the same hash and one would potentially overwrite the other.

Comment: That's not a good example. Both structs are **not** `AnyObject`, structs are value types.

Comment: You can use Any for value types

Comment: @vadian It is theoretical. I don't think you can still mess this up as easy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually triggers a memory leak, check this out:https://pastebin.com/xaQ94TWb . Of course this "shouldn't" theoretically need to be done. But there is a scenario where I might have an arbitrary array of AnyObjects (Imagine I just got a collection of objects from a network call of varying types without a common ancestor.) but I want to index some of these things for whatever reason. I run into a dillema where I want to store these, but I have no way of getting them to a Hashable format.

Comment: @carboncomputed The memory leak looks most interesting. It seems like there is a major bug in the core or we are missing something obvious. As for that collection in the worst case scenario you can create a wrapper to store those objects and so create your common class. With it you can then do anything. Something like `class ObjectWrapper {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let object: Any
    init(object: Any) { self.object = object }
}`